# Does spring-jms 5.x require JMS 2.0?

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I can see in [spring-jms.gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-jms/spring-jms.gradle) that starting with 5.0.0, the dependency to the JMS API changed from 1.1 to 2.0.

However, my question is: does this mean that spring-jms 5.x actually ***requires*** the provider to implement JMS 2.0?

I cannot find a clear requirement for th JMS version in the spring documentation neither in the Javadoc of the main spring-jms classes (like `@EnableJms`). For other JEE APIs like servlet-api or JPA, spring documentation/javadocs make this clearer.

Today, I still use spring 4.x and want to upgrade to 5.x, however I use a JMS provider (Oracle AQ) that implements only JMS 1.1. I would like to be sure whether spring-jms may make use of specific JMS 2.0 features like `JMSContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's backwards-compatible, so as long as you don't try to use any 2.0 features, you should be ok.

Why don't you just give it a try?

Comment: Thank you. While you were giving the answer, I decided to download the spring-jms code and searched in it for calls to ConnectionFactory.createContext(). The only calls are done in the ConnectionFactory decorators like SingleConnectionFactory. So it really seems that the JMS API dependency was upgraded to 2.0 to allow these decorators to become 2.0 compatible, but the main spring-jms components, like DefaultMessageListenerContainer or JmsTemplate seems to not make use of 2.0 features.
Tomorrow I will make some final tests and then I will flag this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @jgslima, what was the result of your testing?

Comment: It does not require JMS 2.0. In fact, after that I opened an issue in Spring (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17583) and they updated the documentation to clarify that.